# java rowfilter regex Locale

Tags: java, regex, jtable, rowfilter

I have a populated `JTable` and have a case insensitive row filter:

```
RowFilter rf = RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)"+filterText.getText(), 0);
```

This works fine until localized letter are used åäöÅÄÖ are entered in the `JTextfield`. The case insensitivity does not work with these letters.

Anyone knows how to make the regex filter working with localized letters?

Comment: Have you tried with the `(?u)` flag for unicode case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering this per my comment:

If you flag your `Pattern` with the [UNICODE_CASE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#UNICODE_CASE) option alongside your case-insensitive option, you should get the results you require.

Since this is a constructed pattern, just prepend `(?iu)` instead of only `(?i)`.

For reference, the documentation says the `UNICODE_CASE` flag...

> Enables Unicode-aware case folding.
>
> When this flag is specified then case-insensitive matching, when
> enabled by the CASE_INSENSITIVE flag, is done in a manner consistent
> with the Unicode Standard. By default, case-insensitive matching
> assumes that only characters in the US-ASCII charset are being
> matched.
>
> Unicode-aware case folding can also be enabled via the embedded flag
> expression (?u).
>
> Specifying this flag may impose a performance penalty.